# Why does entering commands on the DigitalOcean console for Ubuntu droplets make my computer's CPU active the entire time that command is running?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-server, apt-get

I just made a new DigitalOcean account and spun up a Ubuntu droplet.  They have a console connection link in the droplets menu, and I used that.  It opens a separate window from the browser.

When I enter commands like apt-get upgrade, or apt-get install , my local machine's CPU gets *really* busy across the lifetime of that command run.
That seems very strange to me as apt-get should be running on the droplet and not my computer.

What could be causing that kind of behavior?

Comment: In this case I was installing npm.  I observed the same behavior when previously installing nodeJS.

Comment: Very strange - I switched to using ssh on my local machine's command line instead of the DigitalOcean's website "launch console" option.

Now, I'm not having the issue any longer, the processing all happens on the remote machine.  Not sure what exactly that script on their webpage is doing or why it needs to process so much when a command is busy.